# Evaluating a definite integral (Step-by-step solution)

Tags: integration

I would like to know how to evaluate

$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\lambda}xe^{-x\lambda}dx$.

I am getting stuck on the integration by parts and the evaluation of the limit in the factor $uv$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u = x \implies du = dx$. Let $dv = \lambda e^{-x\lambda}dx \implies v = -e^{-x\lambda}$.

$$\begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty}{\lambda}xe^{-x\lambda}\,dx & = -xe^{-x\lambda}\Big|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty -e^{-x\lambda}\,dx \\ \\ & = -\dfrac{x}{e^{x\lambda}} - \frac 1{\lambda e^{x\lambda}}\Big|_0^\infty \\ \\ & = -\dfrac{\lambda x - 1}{\lambda e^{x\lambda}}\Big|_0^\infty \\ \\ & = \Big(\lim_{x \to \infty} -\dfrac{\lambda x - 1}{\lambda e^{x\lambda}}\Big) -\Big( \dfrac{0 - 1}{\lambda e^{0\cdot \lambda}}\Big)\tag{a}\\ \\ &= \Big(\lim_{x \to \infty} -\dfrac{\lambda}{\lambda^2 e^{\lambda x}}\Big) + \frac 1{\lambda}\tag{b} \\ \\ & = 0 + \frac 1\lambda = \frac 1\lambda\end{align} $$

$\lambda > 0 \implies $ the integral converges to $\frac{1}{\lambda}$

Note that in $(a)$ it is appropriate to use L'Hopital. In (b) it is not because the limit is no longer indeterminate.

Comment: Ok, why is $-xe^{-x\lambda}\Big|_0^\infty$ = 0?

Comment: by L'Hopital: $\lim_{x\to \infty} -\dfrac{x}{e^{x\lambda}} = \lim_{x\to \infty} -\dfrac 1{\lambda e^{x\lambda}} = 0$

Comment: @Anonymous I did a more step-by-step of the integral and its evaluation. I hope this helps.

Comment: @amWhy: Also needs a TU +1

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Integrate by parts

$$\int_0^A\lambda x e^{-\lambda x}dx=-xe^{-\lambda x}\Big|_0^A+\int_0^Ae^{-\lambda x}dx$$
and the second integral is simple to evaluate and use the facts
$$\lambda>0,\qquad\lim_{A\to+\infty}A e^{-\lambda A}=\lim_{A\to+\infty} e^{-\lambda A}=0$$

Comment: Ok, why is $-xe^{-\lambda x}\Big|_0^A$

Comment: This term is the $uv\Big|_0^A$ part of the integration by parts and at $0$ the expression is clearly $0$ and at the limit we find $0$ as I explained in the first fact of my answer.

Comment: Nice, Sami! I think I remember this question?! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hints: by parts

$$u=\lambda x\;\;,\;\;u'=\lambda\\
v'=e^{-\lambda x}\;\;,\;\;v=-\frac1\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$$

So your integral equals

$$\left.\lim_{b\to\infty}\big( -xe^{-\lambda x}\right|_0^b+\int\limits_0^b e^{-\lambda x}dx\big)=\ldots$$

The integral converges and its value is $\;\frac1\lambda\;$ , assuming $\;\lambda >0\;$ ...

Comment: Ok, why is $-xe^{-x\lambda}\Big|_0^\infty$ = 0?

Comment: Use l'Hospital:$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac x{e^{\lambda x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{\lambda e^{\lambda x}}=0$$